# Data structures using java

Tags: java

Is it possible to implement data structures using java? If yes can u help me

Comment: Do you know what is data structure?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The more effort you put into your question, the better both the quality and quantity of the answers you'll receive. You'll need to provide a lot more detail for your question to get answered in a reasonable way. What do you mean by "data structures," for instance? Non-class ones? Or stacks / binary trees / etc.?

Comment: **Yes**. What kind of help do you want?

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36701/struct-like-objects-in-java

Comment: I would try these http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Data+Structures+in+Java+tutorial 2.6m results and http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Data+Structures+in+Java+examples 6.7m results.

Answer (score 2):

Java class is a data structure + supporting methods to access/modify the state and variables.

You should learn Java Object Oriented approach.

Also make sure you work through the [Java Collections framework](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html) as all the most commonly used datastructures are already implemented for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ohhhh boy... if you're asking this, I think you need to read up on what a data structure is.

Java has classes (data structure), enums (data structure), arrays (data structure), arraylist (data structure), queue (data structure), stack (data structure), linked list (data structure)...................... even javascript has data structure..

You can see here on what types of data structures are commonly used within this language

[Java data structures (2nd edition)](http://www.theparticle.com/javadata2.html)

Comment: Hey Atticus, running into you a lot today. :-) Please post comments as *comments* rather than answers. Best,

Comment: I am -- looking up an article for him