# Java initializing a pure struct

Tags: java

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
public class myClass
{
  int x;
  int y;
}
```

I have learned c++, so I tried to do this:

```
myClass [] a  = new myClass[5];
for(int i =0; i < 4; i++)
    a[i].x = 0;
```

This doesnt do anything, because all a[i] are null.

I know this is against the basic principal of Java, but there is a product called Alljoyn, which force me to do this, see:

https://www.alljoyn.org/docs-and-downloads/documentation/guide-alljoyn-development-using-java-sdk-rev-j#unique_28

AllJoyn doesnt allow constructor or other methods in the class. Is there any other way to initialize a pure struct?

Comment: Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36701/struct-like-objects-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889034/how-to-initialize-an-array-of-objects-in-java?

Comment: Java graciously adds a default constructor to all classes that define no constructors at all. You can create instances of your `struct` class by calling `new myClass()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not initializing any object, try:

```
myClass [] a  = new myClass[5];
for(int i =0; i < 4; i++){
    a[i] = new myClass();
    a[i].x = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

1. In Java there is no such thing as struct. What you presented is a class.
2. As you observed `a[i]` is `null`, because references in your array are initialized to `null`. You haven't created any object yet. Use `a[i] = new myClass()` in your loop. This 0-argument constructor for class `myClass` will be generated by Java.
3. Names of the classes in Java are written `LikeThis` by convention.
4. `a[i].x = 0` is useless. [Read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) about primitive data types in Java. `int` fields are by default initialized to 0 by compiler.
5. By doing `i < 4` you don't initialize the last element (5th one). Better always do `i < a.length`.

Comment: I wouldn't call these "bad" C++ habits. Struct variable assignment is not a bad idea, it can be useful.

Comment: you have corrected the code. could you add what should OP do in Java, when [s]he conceptually attempts to "initialize struct instances"?

Answer (score 1):

You need to first instialize all the `myClass` of your array:

```
myClass[] a  = new myClass[5];
for(int i =0; i < 4; i++) {
    a[i] = new MyClass();
    a[i].x = 0;
}
```