# comparable used as structure in a binary tree

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree, comparable

I have a binary tree in Java that works nicely. But I want to enhance the data content in the node. Currently I can add values on it doing such as:

```
for( int i = 1; i <=10; i++ )
    t.insert( new Integer( i ) );
```

Which will add the item like this:

```
public void insert( Comparable item ) {
    current = parent = grand = header;
    nullNode.element = item;
    ...
}
```

Here is the format of the tree:

```
private static class RedBlackNode {
    // Constructors
    RedBlackNode( Comparable theElement ) {
        this( theElement, null, null );
    }

    RedBlackNode( Comparable theElement, RedBlackNode lt, RedBlackNode rt ) {
        element  = theElement;
        left     = lt;
        right    = rt;
        color    = RedBlackTree.BLACK;
    }

    Comparable   element;    // The data in the node
    RedBlackNode left;       // Left child
    RedBlackNode right;      // Right child
    int          color;      // Color
}
```

For showing the tree, I do like that:

```
private void printTree( RedBlackNode t ) {
    if( t != nullNode ) {
        printTree( t.left );
        System.out.println(t.element);
        printTree( t.right );
    }
}
```

While when programming in many other languages, the element would be declared as a [struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36701/struct-like-objects-in-java), for this [sample code](http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-implement-red-black-tree/) in Java it is declared as [Comparable](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/03/12/java_comp.html), and currently is only taking one element as integer. My question is, how can I use it similarly as a struct, in order to be able to also manipulate it such as doing in this pseudo code:

```
System.out.println(t.element.valueInt);
System.out.println(t.element.firstNameString);
System.out.println(t.element.lastNameString);
```

I have tried different syntax combinations based on some previous [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718383/java-class-implements-comparable), but none has worked so far.

For the current code version with added comments, check [Gist](https://gist.github.com/emmayazzie).

All suggestions are deeply appreciated.

Comment: I think you will need implement Comparable interface and override compareTo() method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Comparable` is an interface. Any class can implement it. Since the only thing a tree needs to know about its nodes is how to compare, and because `Comparable` provides precisely this kind of knowledge, using `Comparable` is sufficient for the tree.

However, it may not be enough for you, because you may want to know the other attributes that are part of your `Comparable` implementation. For that reason you may choose to make your `RedBlackNode` class *generic* on the exact type of the item that goes into the node, provided that it implements `Comparable`:

```
public class RedBlackTree <T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
    private static class RedBlackNode {
        ...
       T element;
    }
}
```

The rest of your code remains the same. For methods of the tree that expose `Comparable`, such as ones for getting node information, use the generic type `T` instead.

You need to supply the type of the node when creating `RedBlackTree`, like this:

```
RedBlackTree<MyClass> tree = new RedBlackTree<MyClass>();
```

Of course, `MyClass` must implement `Comparable`. The overall effect of the change is that when your code gets an element from the tree, it is strongly typed, letting you access its methods and fields without a cast.

Comment: Would you mind expanding on this syntax: `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`? I am new to generics AND the `Comparable` interface so the combination is blowing my mind....